# Retrieve Class Name/Instance from Object

Tags: java, generics

I am using a common RestTemplate to submit a request to Remote server. Where I am first making a login request, fetching the webToken and then making subsequent request using that token.

In this common RestTemplate, I am logging the request and response. But I want to avert logging the username and password in logging. Following is the example which I am trying to do.

```
 package reflection;

public class TypeCheck {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Object animal = new Animal("Elephant");     
        classType(animal.getClass());
        //Passing Class Type 
         // Output - Unmatched  class reflection.Animal
    }

    private static void classType(Object type) {
        if(type instanceof Animal) {
            System.out.println("Matched  "+ type);
        }

        System.out.println("Unmatched  " + type);
    }

 }

 class Animal {

    String name;

    public Animal(String name) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

 }
```

Now, I want to extract the Class Type (i.e. `reflection.Animal`) from `type` parameter. I tried for `type.getClass().getSimpleName()` and some other methods but not getting better way to do it.

P.S. - Currently I am trying one clumsy way (as I think) to fetch this. But don't know if this is correct or we have some better way to achieve this.

```
if(type.toString().contains("Animal")) {
            System.out.println("Matched "+ type);
        }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to pass `animal` instead of `animal.getClass()`  to the `classType` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply check the same with **istanceof** if you pass the object itself to the classType method rather than the class of it.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Object animal = new Animal("Elephant");
        classType(animal);
    }

    private static void classType(Object type) {
        if (type instanceof Animal) {
            System.out.println("Matched  " + type);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Unmatched  " + type);
        }
    }
```

Or else if you want to check the same with class, you can try the following.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Object animal = new Animal("Elephant");
        classType(animal.getClass());
    }

    private static <T> void classType(Class<T> tClass) {
        if (tClass.getName().equals("Animal")) {
            System.out.println("Matched  " + tClass.getName());
        } else {
            System.out.println("Unmatched  " + tClass.getName());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for prompt response. The option one is not possible as original API gives .class as an argument . So , the option 2, is fine with me and it is close to the  attempt which I am also making. Many thanks it is working for me.